# need support/materials for developing external lists with visual studio 2010

Tags: development, visual-studio, external-content-type, external-list

Up to now, I have mostly used Sharepoint designer to develop external content types and lists.
Due to the lack of source control and for other reasons, we would like to move the development process completely to visual studio. I have some experience developing external content types with visual studio and found a useful [blog](http://blog.voltje.be/2010/07/23/deploying-an-external-list-using-visual-studio-2010/comment-page-1/) how to do the same with external lists. However, I have encountered problems with the list forms (DisplayForm, EditForm) and am in general need for useful material on the topic. I am especially interested if there exist any fundamental problems that stop the successful realization of lists with visual studio.

I would be thankful for any materials, help and support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all interested: a nice microsoft tutorial for building an external list with Visual Studio can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404063%28v=office.14%29.aspx):